# Nothing outputs when add a C# script to modify the text colors in my ListView

Tags: c#, asp.net

So I am doing a webpage in asp.net and when I add this script

```
protected void YourLabel_DataBinding(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Label lbl = (Label)(sender);
    int TWA = (int)(Eval("TWA"));
    lbl.Text = TWA.ToString();
    if (TWA >= 85)
    {
        if (TWA < 90)
        {
            lbl.CssClass = "YellowThis";
        }
        else
        {
            lbl.CssClass = "RedThis";
        }
    }
}
```

and add the databinding line in my listview portion

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <span style="background-color: white;color: #333333; border: 2em; border-width:1em; border-color:black;"> 
        Plant Name: 
        <asp:Label id="PlantLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Plant") %>' />
        <br />
        Department #:
        <asp:Label id="column1Label" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("column1") %>' />
        <br />
        Department Name:
        <asp:Label id="GroupLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Group") %>' />
        <br />
        Job Code:
        <asp:Label id="Job_CodeLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Job_Code") %>' />
        <br /> 
        TWA
        <asp:Label id="TWALabel" runat="server" OnDataBinding="YourLabel_DataBinding" Text='<%# Eval("TWA") %>' />
        <br />
    </span>
</ItemTemplate>
```

My list view will not output at all, but if I remove

```
OnDataBinding="YourLabel_DataBinding"
```

My listview outputs but the colors of TWA don't change based on its value, so what I am doing wrong? Any help would be great

Comment: It's not clear to me where Javascript comes in here...

Comment: That was a mistake on my part, I don't why I added that sorry

Comment: Have you tried adding a break point in the code and seeing where it's faulting?

Comment: @Kevin DeVoe How exactly do I add a break point as I have never done that before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to handle the `OnItemDataBound` event of the ListView and not the data binding event of the actual `Label`. You do this in the markup for your ListView, like this:

```
<asp:ListView ID="YourListView" OnItemDataBound="YourListView_ItemDataBound" runat="server">
```

Then in your code-behind, you can handle the `OnItemDataBound` event, like this:

```
protected void YourListView_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
    {
        Label theTWALabel = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("TWALabel");
        int theTWAValue = Convert.ToInt32(theTWALabel.Text);
        if (theTWAValue >= 85)
        {
            if (theTWAValue < 90)
            {
                theTWALabel.CssClass = "YellowThis";
            }
            else
            {
                theTWALabel.CssClass = "RedThis";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting an error now that says : The name 'TWA' does not exist in the current context

Comment: do you know why it would say that TWA doesn't exist?

Comment: Oops, typo. I have updated the answer to reflect using the correct variable name of `theTWAValue` instead of just `TWA`.

Comment: hmm now I get a error in my ajax portion, it says CS1518: Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct, and it highlights the scriptmanager of the ajax script

Comment: AJAX? Is this inside an `UpdatePanel`?

Comment: actually I fixed that it was missing a }, but CS0123: No overload for 'YourListView_ItemDataBound' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'

Comment: Post the signature for your `ItemDataBound` method.

Comment: ok I fixed that but I am still getting the original problem where nothing outputs

Comment: so it still the same issue as before, once I remove OnItemDataBound from the line, it outputs the data, but still no text change. Is it possible something is wrong with how I am connected to my database?

Comment: So if you put a break point on the line `Label theTWALabel = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("TWALabel");`, then step to the next line what is the `.Text` value of `theTWALabel`? If it is empty, then you have a binding issue.

Comment: This might be the stupidest question you have had the to answer, but how do you add a breakpoint?

Comment: so I figured out how to do the break point and when I add the break point after the  Label theTWALabel = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("TWALabel"); It's a never loads, so its a binding issue.

Comment: how to fix the binding issue exactly?

Comment: Do any of your values (Plant, Group, Job_Code, etc.) come through?

Comment: Nope nothing come through

Comment: Okay, well there is your problem. Do you want to start a new question that has the code posted for how you are trying to bind your data to the ListView?

Comment: Ok I will start a new question

Comment: here is the new question link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17660531/what-is-wrong-with-how-i-am-data-binding-to-my-list-view

Answer (score 0):

The label you need doesn't fire the OnDataBinding event. You have to play with ListView DataBind Event.

[Here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1378659.aspx) you will find an example

In short here is most siginificant code :

```
 protected void ListView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    foreach (ListViewDataItem item in ListView1.Items)
    {
        Label TWALabel = (Label)item.FindControl("TWALabel");
        //Now you have the Label object. do your work.
    }
 }
```