# My listview won't output, is a if post back necessary?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

so I am running a C# function in that is supposed to change the colors of the text based on the value. When I removed the function from the list view it would output the values but when I included it, it would output nothing I have now finally figured out that there is nothing wrong with my function but with how i am binding my data to my list view, so I am wondering what is it I am doing wrong.

Here is my code:

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource id="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:2007  SoundAssist VER 1.0.5  05-12-2011 (2013-06-24)ConnectionString %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:2007 SoundAssist VER 1.0.5  05-12-2011  2013-06-24)ConnectionString.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Plant], [Group No#] AS column1, [Group], [Job Code] AS Job_Code, [TWA], [Job Classification] AS Job_Classification, [Job Function] AS Job_Function, [Job Description] AS Job_Description FROM [Temp Table that contains TWA values] WHERE (([Job Description] = ?) AND ([Group] = ?) AND ([Job Classification] = ?))">
                                                    <SelectParameters>
                                                        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList6" Name="Job_Description" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
                                                        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList4" Name="Group" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
                                                        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList5" Name="Job_Classification" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
                                                    </SelectParameters>
```

and my list view line:

```
<asp:ListView id="YourListView"  runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" OnItemDataBound="YourListView_ItemDataBound" >
```

And my color function:

```
protected void YourListView_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
  {
if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
{
    Label theTWALabel = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("TWALabel");
    int theTWAValue = Convert.ToInt32(theTWALabel.Text);
    if (theTWAValue >= 85)
    {
        if (theTWAValue < 90)
        {
            theTWALabel.CssClass = "YellowThis";
        }
        else
        {
            theTWALabel.CssClass = "RedThis";
        }
    }
}
}
```

And here is the List View:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <span style="background-color: white;color: #333333; border: 2em; border-width:1em; border-color:black;"> 
        Plant Name: 
        <asp:Label id="PlantLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Plant") %>' />
        <br />
        Department #:
        <asp:Label id="column1Label" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("column1") %>' />
        <br />
        Department Name:
        <asp:Label id="GroupLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Group") %>' />
        <br />
        Job Code:
        <asp:Label id="Job_CodeLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Job_Code") %>' />
        <br /> 
        TWA
        <asp:Label id="TWALabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("TWA") %>' />
        <br />
    </span>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Also I didn't type these in (The Sql statement I mean), I used the built in asp.net connection wizard to do this, and it created it all for me.

Edit: If there is any other info you need to help answer this question, please comment

Edit2: Is it possible that I need a if post back function?

Comment: @Karl Anderson do you know why its not working by any chance?

Comment: By the number of views and lack of replies, either my question is really stupid or confusing, but I am 99 percent sure its just stupid....

Comment: If there is something wrong with my question can some please tell what I need to fix as I am have been stuck on this problem for a while

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint and stepped through the code to at least see the behavior?

Comment: @Dustin Laine Yes I have, I added a break to this line: int theTWAValue = Convert.ToInt32(theTWALabel.Text);, found that it was not outputing anything and I was told that is a databinding issue so how do i fix that

Comment: Well, do you have blanks or NULL's coming into that label? If you are converting a blank or NULL to an INT it will fail. You should get an exception stating that. It succeeds?

Comment: No I have no blank nulls coming into that label

Comment: Make sure that `TWALabel` is the id that is being rendered to the browser when you run the application.

Comment: @EmmanuelRC it is, and I still get no output

Comment: @EmmanuelRC so Do you have any ideas on how I could fix this problem

Comment: The only reason for your variable `TheTWAValue` having no value in your code, even when you specified some text for it, it'd be because the `FindControl` method is not finding a control with that ID. But you telling me that it is the exact same ID that is being rendered to the client in the browser when you run the application... I'd need to try it myself to get to some useful conclusion. Try your `FindControl` like `((Label)Page.FindControl("TWALabel"));` and tell me how it goes.

Comment: @EmmanuelRC no output still

Comment: Can you show us the html markup of the rendered label? Not from the IDE but from View Source, Firebug, etc...

Comment: How did you verified that `TWALabel` is the ID that's being rendered?

Comment: <span id="YourListView_TWALabel_0"></span>

Comment: Then in your `FindControl` method use `YourListView_TWALabel_0` as parameter instead of `TWALabel`.

Comment: @EmmanuelRC Well that was from inspecting the elements in google chrome, in the source though the id=TWALabel, so do still want to do that

Comment: Yeah, in your `FindControl` try using the ID you get from the inspection.

Comment: @EmmanuelRC I changed it to YourListView_TWALabel_0 and I still got no output

Comment: @EmmanuelRC I have added my list view for you to view

Comment: @JayGee do you have any other ideas on how to get this list view to output

Comment: What version of .NET are you using?

Comment: @DustinLaine i am using version 4.5

Comment: What does the version of .NET going to affect?

Comment: Instead of using `e.Item.FindControl` you could try looping through controls. `foreach (Control c in e.Item.Controls) { if (c.id.contains("TWA")) \\do something }`

Comment: @JayGee You should add this as an answer; currently it's going to be hard for someone who has this problem to follow what the actual answer is since it's in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to access the controls in the `YourListView_ItemDataBound` event handler, and at that point the `ListView` doesn't have loaded yet.

Try adding to your `ListView` the event handler `onLoad` and inside that method then you work with your items like:

```
protected void YourListView_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label theTWALabel;
    int theTWAValue;
    foreach (ListViewItem item in YourListView.Items)
    {
        theTWALabel = (Label)item.FindControl("TWALabel");
        theTWAValue = Convert.ToInt32(theTWALabel.Text);
        if (theTWAValue >= 85)
        {
            if (theTWAValue < 90)
                theTWALabel.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
            else
                theTWALabel.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to set the colors with your `CSS` class or in the way I wrote above? Because I tested it and it works just fine.

Comment: the way you wrote above, I deleted the YourListView_ItemDataBound, added the onload function that you wrote

Answer (score 1):

You could try to loop through the controls rather than using FindControl.

```
if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
{
    foreach (Control c in e.Item.Controls) 
    {
        if (c is Label && c.ID.Contains("TWALabel"))
        {
            Label theTWALabel = (Label)c
            int theTWAValue = Convert.ToInt32(theTWALabel.Text);
            if (theTWAValue >= 85)
            {
                if (theTWAValue < 90)
                {
                    theTWALabel.CssClass = "YellowThis";
                }
                else
                {
                    theTWALabel.CssClass = "RedThis";
                }
            }            
        }
    }
}
```

Even if .Net modifies the ID name, you can check to see if the ID has the substring TWALabel and find your control that.

There is probably a better way to do it, but I can't think of another way that I know will work.

Comment: How exactly do implement this? Is this an onload function?

Comment: @friendo9876 This would go in your `YourListView_ItemDataBound` function

Answer (score 0):

The YourListView_ItemDataBound method is called as the List view is being data bound. This is at the point where asp.net is creating a row in your grid for each row in your data source, so you will not be able to access the posted back data by pulling it from the control like you are doing. It is too late, as that old version of the grid has already been discarded.

I think you can either

- Have the TWALabel autopostback to the server and create an OnChange event.
- Parse the Request.Params to find the posted back value for each row
- Try and pull what you need earlier in the page lifecycle before the databinding occurs. I think you would still have access to this data during Page_Load