# Is there a way using javascript not C# to change the text color of a list view?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I was wondering if there was a way to change the text color of specific line in a list view based its value, using javascript only, no c#. Specifically I want to be able do this, if the TWA value is less 90 the text should be green, else be red.

Here is my code:

```
 <asp:ListView id="YourListView"  runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3"  EnableViewState="False"  EditIndex="0" SelectedIndex="0">                                                                                                                                                               


<ItemTemplate>  
Plant Name:

<asp:Label id="PlantLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Plant") %>' />
    <br />
            Department #:

            <asp:Label id="column1Label" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("column1") %>' />
            <br />
                    Department Name:

                <asp:Label id="GroupLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Group") %>' />

                   Job Code:

            <asp:Label id="Job_CodeLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Job_Code") %>' />

            <br />

            TWA:

            <asp:Label id="TWALabel"  runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("TWA") %>' />

            <br />

         Job Classification:

        <asp:Label id="Job_ClassificationLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Job_Classification") %>' />

            <br />

            Job Function:

            <asp:Label id="Job_FunctionLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Job_Function") %>' />
```

Thanks for any help given

Comment: Almost everyday you ask how to color `ListView`. Prefer way is to use `ItemDataBound` which `Karl Anderson` has answered your question. http://stackoverflow.com/a/17658308/296861

Comment: That is using C# not javascript

Comment: JavaScript is not the way of coloring `ListView`; it is just a hack and difficult to maintain. What is the reason behind using JavaScript for coloring `ListView`? If you do not follow the proper way, it'll eat you alive in the future maintenance.

Comment: You would be better off using databound event. You are using a ListView which is a server side control. Which means everything is done at server and returned to the client. Using JavaScript in this scenario would be an overkill. Why add complexity when you are not gaining any benefits at all?

Comment: OK, I was just really getting sick and tired of this C# script not working, i have been trying to figure what the hell is wrong with for past few days, so i just kind of given up. That is why i was seeing if there was a way in javascript, but I guess i will go back again and see if I can figure out why the c# code is working. Sorry for wasting your guys time

Answer (score 0):

If jQuery is an option for your JavaScript, you could use its .each selector to iterate over each TWA label item, evaluate the value and apply either an inline style or css class based on the value.

Answer (score 0):

ListView does not have a CSSClass attribute.

One alternative that would work is to wrap the contents of the list view in a div and apply 
styling to the div.

As an example:

**Markup:**

```
<asp:ListView>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div id="listViewDiv">
            <!-- Content goes here. -->
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
document.getElementById('listViewDiv').style.width = '300px';
```